# How do I detect and then base an action off of when one of my generated buttons(from a 2D button array) is clicked

Tags: c#, button, multidimensional-array, windows-forms-designer

So i am generating buttons like this and what i need to do is make those buttons disappear when they are clicked.

````
        {
            Button[,] buttonArray = new Button[10, 10];
            int xx = 0;
            int yy;
            for (int x = 50; x <= 430; x+=40)
            {
                yy = 0;
                for (int y = 50; y <= 430; y+=40)
                {
                    buttonArray[xx, yy] = new Button();
                    buttonArray[xx, yy].Size = new Size(40, 40);
                    buttonArray[xx, yy].Location = new Point(x, y);
                    this.Controls.Add(buttonArray[xx, yy]);
                    
                    yy++;
                }
                xx++;
            }
            
        }```
````

Comment: Maybe start with one button. Figure out to make it "disappear". Google, docs, tutorials - even SO could help. Then perhaps try two buttons. Then two buttons in an array. Then maybe four buttons in a 2x2 array.